# Are FTP accounts available in VestaCP for free?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

I'm planning to deploy VestaCP on a VPS hosted in OVH. I know that VestaCP needs a license for the file manager.  Does it include free FTP accounts to manage my future site in WordPress? Do I need to pay for the use of FTP accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pricing](https://vestacp.com/pricing/) page says:

> All core functionality is free.

and only lists a chroot sFTP package for sale.  The [features](https://vestacp.com/features/) page lists VsFTPD or ProFTPD under the core features.

I take this to mean that VsFTPD and ProFTPD are included as part of the free core features.  You would only need to pay for the chroot sFTP if you want to give users access to sFTP without allowing them to see content outside their home directory.